# Azure management certificate error in vagrant

Tags: azure, certificate, vagrant

I am trying to spin up a VM in Azure using Vagrant. Following this tutorial :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2014/06/19/building-your-ubuntu-php-development-box-on-azure-using-vagrant.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

But I got stuck in this line

> azure.mgmt_certificate = 'C:\Dev\management_cert.pfx'

The error I got is following

> λ vagrant up --provider=azure
>   C:/Users/hoss329549/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/azure-0.6.4/lib/azure/base_management/base_management_service.rb:48:in `rescue in initialize': Management certificate not valid. Error: PKCS12_parse: mac verify failure (RuntimeError)

I have tried to download the publishsettings and renamed extension to pfx but didn't work. Didn't find much blog/articles that talks about this area. How can I solve this issue?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by myself. What I did was downloaded the publishsettings file from Azure portal and renamed the file to pfx by keeping only the management certificate xml block into it.