# Trouble with Azure gem for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, rubygems

I'm trying to work with Azure queues, and whenever I try and instantiate a new queue `azure_queue_service = Azure::QueueService.new` I get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Azure::QueueService`. I've made sure the gem is installed, and required. Configured both the account name and key, but no luck.

Research tends to point towards the gem isn't loaded, but all my other gems are loaded, so I don't think that's it.

Thanks in advance

pc

Comment: Depends on which gem version you are using. In the latest code, I see its updated to Azure::Queue::QueueService, so worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
azure_queue_service = Azure::Queue::QueueService.new
```

not just Azure::.

Next, you want to get the certificates ([reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/service_management/README.md#storage)). Sometimes, the issue with PKCS12 happens, and [that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969451/azure-management-certificate-error-in-vagrant) happens to be helpful.